# dynamically create og tags for images for facebook

Tags: facebook, image, tags, facebook-opengraph

I need to pull the image that facebook will display from the database

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta property="og:url" content="xxx/public/GigGuide2.asp?A=<%=iActName%>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Live Gig Guide"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<%=HiRes%>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MyEpod"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Live Gig Guide"/>
```

Can this be done? What am I doing wrong?

The Open Graph Object Debugger show i have all the tags right except the image tag and i need to be able to bring the photo of the act up with their page etc??

Comment: What's `"<%=HiRes%>"`?

Answer (score 0):

The og:image tag can only use a URL as content, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/

You need to create a separate script which you reference for example like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="xxx/public/ActImage.asp?A=<%=iActName%>"/>
```

and the ActImage.asp script will pull the image from the db and set the correct headers etc. As you havent given any details how the images are stored in the db, this is the most detailed answer I can give.